Relation between chemical potential and activity for a substance in a chemical reaction?
For a chemical reaction, the relation between its Gibbs free energy $\Delta G$ and reaction quotient $Q$ is:
$$\Delta G=\Delta G^o+RT\ln Q \tag{1}$$
This can be derived from an analogous relation between the chemical potential of a compounds $\mu_i$ and its activity $a_i$:
$$\mu_i=\mu^o_i+RT\ln a_i\tag{2}$$
However, when I looked up the derivation of this equation, Wikipedia stated that activity is defined in this manner in terms of chemical potential. But where did this relation come from? Is this purely experimental or has a theoretical basis?

Hint: Before asking, always try to do at least some cursory searching, as the topic may be already present in details on various sites, including this one.  My recommendation is using targeted search like site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org    // Especially the LibreTexts site is dedicated on education and there are tons of materials presented in educative form you can get lots of accessible info.

Ok, my bad, should have done some more research. By the way, thanks.

The ln(Q) term is related to the entropy of mixing, which can be derived using the statistical definition of entropy, see e.g. here or there

The equation (2) is the definition of TD activity as an implicit function. I.e. not $a=f( \mu ,\mu^{\circ}, T)$, but after small change as $f(\mu,\mu^{\circ},T,a)=0$.
Definitions are not derived nor can be confirmed nor refuted.
Activity $a$ defined by the equation
$$\mu_i=\mu^{\circ}_i+RT\ln a_i \tag{2}$$
is equal to molar fraction $x$ of a solute in ideal solution, if the pure substance is considered as the standard state with $\mu = \mu^{\circ}$.
There is introduced the activity coefficient gamma: $a = \gamma \cdot x$
By other words, activity is the molar fraction of a solute, if it had behaved ideally and if it had the same chemical potential as the real solute of molar fraction $x$.
For some other cases is the standard state differently, like for electrolyte solutions where $\lim_{c \to 0}{a} = c$, where is used approximate proportionality between molar concentration and molar fraction, where $a = \gamma \cdot c$.

What have you explained in the last part? I am not able to understand.

Activity of ions in diluted solutions, following the Debye-Hueckel equation.

Ok, I got the activity part. but what happens to the standard state as a solution is infinitely diluted? I think that part is somewhat incomplete in the paragraph.

I have recently posted the answer that addresses this. It is based on approximate proportionality of x and c.

The expression
$$\mu_i=\mu^o_i+RT\ln a_i$$
originates during application of the definition of the Gibbs free energy in differential form
$$dG = Vdp - SdT$$
to an ideal gas at constant temperature:
$$dG = \frac{RT}{p}dp$$
Integrating,
$$G = G^\circ + RT \ln \left( \frac{p}{p^\circ} \right)$$
For an ideal mixture of non-interacting gases it follows that
$$\mu = \mu^\circ + RT \ln  \left( \frac{p_i}{p^\circ} \right)$$
The same form can be retained for non-ideal gases and fluids in general by introducing the concept of activity
$$a_i = \frac{p_i}{p^\circ} $$
such that
$$\mu = \mu^\circ + RT \ln  a_i$$
